# Perf Error: The sys_perf_event_open() syscall returned with 22 (Invalid argument) for event (msr/tsc/)

Tags: profiling, perf, tsc, msr

I am using perf to monitor the system for certain events. However, I get the following error and I have no idea where it comes from,as the event is listed in perf list

**sudo perf record -e msr/tsc/ -a**

```
Error:
The sys_perf_event_open() syscall returned with 22 (Invalid argument) for event (msr/tsc/).
/bin/dmesg may provide additional information.
No CONFIG_PERF_EVENTS=y kernel support configured?
```

How can I check No CONFIG_PERF_EVENTS=y kernel support configured?

**Some test results:

```
sudo dmesg | grep "perf\|pmu"**
[    0.029179] ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: Set to 'normal', was 'performance'
[    0.029179] ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: View and update with x86_energy_perf_policy(8)
[ 9475.406967] perf: interrupt took too long (2509 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79500
[ 9475.990901] perf: interrupt took too long (3146 > 3136), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 63500
[ 9476.886941] perf: interrupt took too long (3942 > 3932), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50500
[76057.268195] perf: interrupt took too long (4934 > 4927), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 40500
[167368.007839] perf: interrupt took too long (6171 > 6167), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 32250
[168338.165608] perf: interrupt took too long (7804 > 7713), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 25500
```

**perf list |grep msr**

```
  msr/aperf/                                         [Kernel PMU event]
  msr/mperf/                                         [Kernel PMU event]
  msr/pperf/                                         [Kernel PMU event]
  msr/smi/                                           [Kernel PMU event]
  msr/tsc/
```

**sudo uname -a**
Linux bla 4.9.0-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.130-2 (2018-10-27) x86_64 GNU/Linux

**sudo /proc/config.gz** returns command not found
Any help/ideas are appreciated.

Comment: What system are you using?  Ubuntu?  Arch Linux?  `uname -a` output?  Depending on how your kernel was compiled, it might have a `/proc/config.gz` containing the config options it was built with.

Comment: I edited the question and added the requested data. I use Debian

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to collect this information with `perf record` by using group sampling. For example, the following command

```
perf record -a -e '{cycles,msr/aperf/,msr/tsc/}:S'
```

collects values of all three events based on the  `cycle` (first counter) overflow. The undocumented `:S` modifier is necessary, it makes sure that only the leader of the group triggers samples. For seeing this information, you use `perf report --group`, the parameter may not be necessary. I'm afraid the actual values for each sample are only visible in the very verbose `perf script -D`.

Answer (score 3):

There was a [patch](https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/patch/586331/) introduced in `perf` to support MSR Performance Monitoring Units. These MSR PMUs support free-running MSR counters. These counters include time and frequency-based counters like `TSC`, `IA32_APERF`, `IA32_MPERF` and `IA32_PPERF`.

These MSR events do not support sampling modes. As visible by [this](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.9/source/arch/x86/events/msr.c#L149) line of code in the linux kernel(v4.9) source code.

Snippet:

`if event->attr.sample_period) /* no sampling */
        return -EINVAL;`

`perf_events` can instrument in three ways (counting events, sampling events and bpf events). Remember that when you run `perf record`, you are now invoking the sampling mode. Even though you do not explicitly specify the `sampling period`, internally sampling is happening at a default sampling frequency.

To count `msr` events, you need to run `perf_events` in counting/aggregation mode. You run `perf stat` for this --

```
perf stat -e msr/tsc/ -a

^C

Performance counter stats for 'system wide':

 34,83,07,96,035      msr/tsc/                                                    

 2.419151644 seconds time elapsed
```

Read [this](http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html) to understand more about counting and sampling events/modes.

Comment: Just FYI I would point you to my answer explaining that it is in fact possible to `perf record` these counters by using group recording with a sampling-capable group leader.